# How to pull HealthKit steps data when user unlock the phone?

Tags: ios, background-process, healthkit

The following is my code to pull `HealthKit` steps data in the background and upload to server.

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

   var window: UIWindow?

   let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

   func startObservingHeightChanges() {

       let sampleType =  HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight)

       var query: HKObserverQuery = HKObserverQuery(sampleType: sampleType, predicate: nil, updateHandler: self.heightChangedHandler)

       healthKitStore.executeQuery(query)
       healthKitStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType(sampleType, frequency: .Immediate, withCompletion: {(succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!) in

           if succeeded{
               println("Enabled background delivery of weight changes")
           } else {
               if let theError = error{
                   print("Failed to enable background delivery of weight changes. ")
                   println("Error = \(theError)")
               }
           }
       })
   }


   func heightChangedHandler(query: HKObserverQuery!, completionHandler: HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler!, error: NSError!) {

       // Here you need to call a function to query the height change

       // Send the notification to the user
       var notification = UILocalNotification()
       notification.alertBody = "Changed height in Health App"
       notification.alertAction = "open"
       notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

       UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

       completionHandler()
   }

   func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success:Bool, error:NSError!) -> Void)!) {

       // 1. Set the types you want to read from HK Store
       let healthKitTypesToRead = [
        HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth),
        HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBloodType),
        HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight),
        HKObjectType.workoutType()
       ]

       // 2. Set the types you want to write to HK Store
       let healthKitTypesToWrite = [
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMassIndex),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning),
        HKQuantityType.workoutType()
       ]

       // 3. If the store is not available (for instance, iPad) return an error and don't go on.
       if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
           let error = NSError(domain: "any.domain.com", code: 2, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"HealthKit is not available in this Device"])

           if( completion != nil ) {
               completion(success:false, error:error)
           }
           return;
       }

       // 4.  Request HealthKit authorization
       healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(Set(healthKitTypesToWrite), readTypes: Set(healthKitTypesToRead)) { (success, error) -> Void in
           if( completion != nil ) {

               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), self.startObservingHeightChanges)
               completion(success:success,error:error)
           }
       }
   }

   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

       application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert | .Badge | .Sound, categories: nil))

       self.authorizeHealthKit { (authorized,  error) -> Void in
           if authorized {
               println("HealthKit authorization received.")
           }
           else {
               println("HealthKit authorization denied!")
                   if error != nil {
                   println("\(error)")
               }
           }
       }

       return true
   }


   //Rest of the defaults methods of AppDelegate.swift

}
```

I want to pull `HealthKit` steps data when user unlock the phone.
But from my testing, when user has just turn on the screen(didn’t enter the passcode yet), it works and try to pull `HealthKit` steps data. Then it fails because of the phone is still locked. When I enter the passcode, it doesn’t working because it has tried already. 
How can I call `healthKitStore.enableBackgroundDeliveryForType` method when user "unlock" the phone? Does any other way to pull HealthKit steps data when the user unlock the phone?